# Cannot query "ABC": Must be "Image" instance

Tags: django, django-models

I came across an error message within the model.py. I would appreciate if you guys could give me some assistance on this; the following are parts of the model.py:

```
class WorkJob(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    share = models.ForeignKey(FShare, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    aftId = models.ForeignKey(AftId, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        if self.aftId:
            return self.aftId.aft
        else:
            return str('AFT-NA')

class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    imagingJob = models.OneToOneField(WorkJob, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    md5 = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    originalCopy = models.ForeignKey(Disc, related_name='originalCopy', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    workingCopy = models.ForeignKey(Disc, related_name='workingCopy', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.imagingJob.fileShare.identifier

class Copy(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    disc = models.ForeignKey(Disc, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='copy')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def aftId(self):
        return self.image.imagingJob.aftId.aft
```

the next class is the one that I have problems.

```
class TFI(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    createDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_OPTIONS, default=0)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def check_third(self):
        if self.status == 5:
            im = 0
            third_imajob = WorkJob.objects.filter(share=self.share)
            for ima in third_imajob:
                if Copy.objects.filter(image__exact=ima.aftId).exists():
                    # some code blablabla
                else:
                    break
```

The line that the error message says that it is problematic is:

```
if Copy.objects.filter(image__exact=ima.aftId).exists():
```

I am not certain why is it saying that the instance must be with Image. The line clearly is extracting from class Copy and WorkJob. I did see that that the Copy.image has a foreignkey reference to class Image but I am not certain how to troubleshoot this. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: following is also a part of the code and the above code has also been added.

```
class AftId(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    aft = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    assignedTo = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.aft
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare some `aftID` instances and `Image`.

I can't see your `aftId` model but I guess it has an image foreign key field, so your query should be `Copy.objects.filter(image__exact=ima.aftId.image).exists()`

Comment: Hey May.D, Thank you for your input. I did add aftId model as part of the Edit. I did the changes as you mentioned but I am getting an "Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ABC'" on the same line. Could you give some further insights?

Comment: Your `AftId` model doesn't have a reference to your `Image` model, so I don't understand what you are trying to compare

Comment: Also a few generic remarks, you don't need to implement `id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)` as Django will take care of this for you. Moreover, you don't need the `__exact` lookup as it's the default one. So you can juste write  `image = ...`